# How can I find (programatically) triggerable objects in salesforce?

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to find object on which trigger can be written.How can I get that objects? 
Can anyone suggest the way to do that?

Comment: this can be done with the Tooling API - Describe - see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_describesobjects_rest.htm?search_text=trigger

Answer (score 1):

you can use eclipse. Open eclipse --> create new trigger there you can see available sobject list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that way but I want to fetch that objects and want to use it for further requirement. can getDescribecall be useful for this? I can get updatable objects by getDescribe call but I want triggerable. Can you suggest any other way?